# KPI for Sharepoint Online hooked into Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, kpi

I've been tasked with looking for replacements for our current KPI system as we move from Sharepoint 2013 to Sharepoint Online.

In our current system we use a KPI web part that hooks into Excel Spreadsheets and displays the data on web pages in a standard KPI display.

I've already found some options for going to online, the spreadsheets can be displayed directly on the page if we want, I can use formatted columns in a Sharepoint List for a dynamic KPI display but it doesn't hook into the Excel Spreadsheet as far as I know such that updating the spreadsheet updates the list. Or we can use Microsoft Dynamics, which is expensive and I don't know if it can hook into Excel Spreadsheets.

Is there another option for hooking into an Excel Spreadsheet hosted in a Sharepoint library and displaying the data in Sharepoint Online in a KPI format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with Power BI to do the data visualization and integrate it with SharePoint online?

[How to build KPI dashboard in Power BI.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-kpi)  [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sq4oRnCGUAE)

[Quickstart: Connect to data in Power BI Desktop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-quickstart-connect-to-data)

[Refresh a dataset created from an Excel workbook on OneDrive, or SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-excel-file-onedrive)

[Embed with report web part in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-embed-report-spo)